# Create Tiles for a raster(georeferenced) to use in leaflet

Tags: raster, gdal, leaflet, tiles

I have raster, with each pixel containing some data. 
What i want is to split a large image with each pixel's color is determined by its value, to show on leaflet layer.How to go about this ?

raster 'Size is 19839, 17000'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TileMill works with GeoTIFF at least: https://www.mapbox.com/tilemill/docs/guides/reprojecting-geotiff/

Comment: successfully created images , implemented with angular , everything is fine , but if you could tell me how do i do this on console instead of gui like tilemill or maptiler ? Thanks.

Comment: I guess mapnik is the way to go then?

Comment: can you provide me some examples ? or links or articles ?